# Get Experience Forms Performance statistics using API

Tags: sitecore-forms, performance, api

Is there an API to use the form performance? I'm using Sitecore 9.3.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The performance data is retrieve using the action **GetFormStatistics** from **Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Controllers.ReportsController** class.

I added below the action **GetFormStatistics**:

```
namespace Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Controllers
{
  [ServicesController("Forms.Reports")]
  [CamelCaseJson]
  [SitecoreAuthorize(Roles = "sitecore\\Forms Editor,sitecore\\Forms Publisher,sitecore\\Forms Data Administrator")]
  [ValidateHttpAntiForgeryToken]
  [SetFormMode]
  public class ReportsController : ServicesApiController
  {
    private readonly IFormBuilderContext _formBuilderContext;
    private readonly IFormStatisticsProvider _formStatisticsDataProvider;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ReportsController(
      IFormStatisticsProvider formStatisticsDataProvider,
      ILogger logger,
      IFormBuilderContext formBuilderContext)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) formStatisticsDataProvider, nameof (formStatisticsDataProvider));
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) logger, nameof (logger));
      this._formStatisticsDataProvider = formStatisticsDataProvider;
      this._logger = logger;
      this._formBuilderContext = formBuilderContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("FormStatistics")]
    [ValidateModelState]
    [ResponseType(typeof (FormStatisticsResult))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetFormStatistics(
      [FromUri] FormReportParameters reportParameters)
    {
      if (reportParameters == null)
        return (IHttpActionResult) this.BadRequest(Translate.Text("Invalid or missing parameters."));
      Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> dateRange = ReportsController.ParseDateRange(reportParameters);
      try
      {
        FormStatistics formStatistics = this._formStatisticsDataProvider.GetFormStatistics(reportParameters.FormId, dateRange.Item1, dateRange.Item2);
        if (formStatistics == null)
          return (IHttpActionResult) this.NotFound();
        FormStatisticsResult content = new FormStatisticsResult()
        {
          UniqueViews = formStatistics.Visits,
          Abandonments = formStatistics.Dropouts,
          AbandonmentRate = formStatistics.DropoutRate
        };
        foreach (FieldStatistics formFieldStatistic in this._formStatisticsDataProvider.GetFormFieldStatistics(reportParameters.FormId, dateRange.Item1, dateRange.Item2))
          content.Fields.Add(this.CreateFieldStatisticsResult(formFieldStatistic));
        return (IHttpActionResult) this.Ok<FormStatisticsResult>(content);
      }
      catch (XdbDisabledException ex)
      {
        this._logger.Warn(ex.Message, (object) this);
        return (IHttpActionResult) this.StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
      }
    }
```

You can call this url :

**`yourhosturl/api/ssc/forms/reports/reports/formstatistics?formId=68ff3538-9528-4b4d-b374-bf85442f0bb1&startDate=2020-10-06T21%3A00%3A00.000Z&endDate=2020-10-14T20%3A59%3A59.000Z&utcOffset=-18`** to get the response from the action.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I have another question does sitecore save the statistics of the answers? for example if a raido button with yes and another is no is their a statistics for each answer

Comment: if the yes button is a submit button and you add an action to save data it will save the statistics, otherwise it will not save them